# Return results into div of different page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I Just want to return results from a php file into  a div located on a different page. this is what i have done, #box is the div class located on a different page.
Any help will be appreciated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("button").click(function(){
    var str= "hellos";


    $.post('INCLUDES/show.php',{t: str},
    function(output)
    {

        $(#box').html(output).show();
    });
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: so, this script and the #box div are located in two different pages altogether? also, do you know that #box refers to the id attribute, not the class

Comment: What do you mean by `located on a different page`, you can't use javascript to access a different page's dom.

Comment: @ggreiner yea the script and the #box id is located on different pages, yea cheers do, sorry just bit wrecked

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've ever done this is with [window.opener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp), but I'm not an expert on using it and would suggest looking through the docs more on it.